# Get distinct records using lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda

I have Revision class object which can have multiple detail class objects. And in each detail class i can have multiple prefixes(Its reference type class). Now i want to get distinct prefix records for each detail in a revision. How can i do that using lambda expression?

```
List<ReferenceType> prefixes = (List<ReferenceType>)revision.Details
    .GroupBy(p => p.Prefix.Id)
    .Select(grp => grp.First());
```

All i want is select distinct records of prefixes in details class. The above code is not working its throwing error like throwing error cannot convert details to reference type. How to get dictinct prefixes in a Revision -> Details -> Prefixes??

Comment: @Tronics Try it and find out.  Does it work?

Comment: What error are you getting with the code you've presented? That cast looks very suspicious... :)

Comment: That cast won't work.  Should use `ToList()` instead and forget the cast.

Comment: What criteria are you using to determine Distinct?  Right now you are using grp.First which is getting only one item.  Distinct won't work because you have a class which has multiple properties.  You need some criteria like IEquals to determine which properties are used for the criteria.

Comment: Something along the lines of this might do the trick: `bar prefixes = revision.Details
    .GroupBy(p => p.Prefix.Id)
    .Select(grp => grp.FirstOrDefault()).Distinct().ToList();`

Comment: I updated my post please check

Comment: You still haven't provided a reproducible example, a description of the problem, or a clear description of what you're trying to do and what you expect to happen.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me...

revision.Details.Where(x => x.Prefix != null).Select(y => y.Prefix).Distinct()